# Memoryleak hunting in monotouch and mvvmcross using profiller tool

Tags: xamarin.ios, garbage-collection, mvvmcross

I have been working to eliminate memory leaks in our mono touch and learned a lot in last couple of days e.g. that it is almost always some event that needs to be unhook before garbage collecting is succeeded :)

But now I have been playing around with the profiller tool and I can see that most of the memory is used by strings (or it seems), please see the following screendump:
[image]

[image]

But as you can see some memory is also used by mono. I have been working our viewmodels and views and most of these are garbage collected correct. If I look into the strings they sometimes are referenced by  and I have no clue what to do with this info.
 Do you guys have any suggestion if I can reduce the amount of memory used by strings :) I have tried to find any tutorial or similar that might enlight what these numbers means, but with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Some answers from my personal experience:

- For tutorial I only really know about http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Deployment%252c_Testing%252c_and_Metrics/Monotouch_Profiler
- I find the 'Inverse References' option one of the most useful features - what matter is not that you have a lot of strings, but rather what owns those strings.
- I find the best way of hunting these bugs is to reproduce them in a simple test harness and/or test sequence - as apps get bigger and I use more and more components - MvvmCross, JSON.Net, SQLite-net, etc - in more and more asynchronous ways, then I find I need to cut down on the number of these components to identify the leaks.
- Once you have a simple test harness, the filter option in the HeapShot helps - as it lets you focus on classes which are in known namespaces.
- Once you have a simple test harness, then comparing two HeapShot's can also help - which actions in your test UI cause what increases between HeapShots?

  **Differences are what matter** - some libraries deliberately cache things in memory - e.g. some of the PropertyInfo's in your HeapShot images might be deliberately cached by one of the libraries in order to improve deserialisation speed.

---

For easier cross-referencing, adding links to linked questions:

- [Garbage collecting issue with Custom viewbinding in mono touch and mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771064/garbage-collecting-issue-with-custom-viewbinding-in-mono-touch-and-mvvmcross?rq=1)
- [when to release objects in mono touch / mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688044/when-to-release-objects-in-mono-touch-mvvmcross?rq=1)
- [MVVMCross - SqlBits Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735764/mvvmcross-sqlbits-memory-leak?rq=1)
- [Helping the GC in mono droid using mvvmCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494804/helping-the-gc-in-mono-droid-using-mvvmcross?rq=1)

Comment: One other point... if you've been doing this for a few days, then you are now an expert - would love to see a post somewhere about what you've learnt (good and bad)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Stuart's great answer, I'd like to stress that you should profile on device. Execution on device is tweaked for runtime performance, while the simulator is tweaked for *build* performance (so that the edit-debug cycle is as fast as possible). Among other things it means that in the simulator more memory is used at runtime than in on device.